# Illustrator creating shapes tips

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have the next project:

[image]

I want that the rectangle with lines shape gets the form of the background image floor lines. I mean, the idea is that these rectangle takes an 3d effect. I try to select anchor points and I cannot do it.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: How are the lines create? Are they separate objects within the rectangle or pattern??

Comment: Each line is inside the rectangle and yes, they are separated objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy method is to merely use the **Free Transform Tool**.

Select the rectangle and the lines. I would **Group** them, but that's not mandatory.

Then grab the **Free Transform Tool** from the **Toolbar**. You can then choose the *Free Distort tool* from the little tool popup ....
Select it and click-drag the top, center, handle.

[image]

And just drag to match what you want....

[image]

Using the **Free Transform Tool** *without* using the Free Distort tool in the popup....

1. Click the top center handle
2. *then* hold down the <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> key
3. *then* drag.

You have to hold the key *exactly* between the click and any drag operation. If you mistakenly click-drag just a little, then hold the modifier key, it won't work. 
(This can take practice).

<sub>I'm using an older version of AI, so I don't have the Free Distort *tool* available. Which is why I detailed the keyboard shortcut. These shortcuts work in *all* versions of AI but the extra *tools* for free transform only pop up in more recent CC versions. The shortcut has the *exact* same functionality as the free distort tool.</sub>

---

I *wish* the bounding box stayed accurate to the shape, but it won't.

From this point, after distortion, because the bounding box gets reset to a standard rectangle, further distortions can be tricky or problematic. Therefor moving anchors to match anything is often easier if necessary.

Comment: Who is the man? You are the man. Thank you!!